# Websphere 9.0.0.11 unable to run application using java1.8?

Tags: java, spring, deployment, websphere, war

I'm trying to deploy war file on Websphere 9.0.0.11 but we are getting the error. Although I'm able to run the file locally on tomcat and Similarly, when I try to add old war files they are working fine. No changes are made in the code too.

Websphere version: 9.0.0.11
Apache Maven 3.5.3
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation

```
MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=Default01Node,version=9.0.0.11,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=Default01Cell,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
unable to open input stream for resource
org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.class in archive
WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.core.resources-3.14.0.jar
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException


W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR
unable to open input stream for resource org/osgi/service/application
/ApplicationAdminPermission.class in archive WEB-INF/lib
/org.eclipse.equinox.app-1.6.0.jar java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) at
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) at
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) at
com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)
```

Comment: You need to clarify when this error appears and format properly full stack trace. And you cannot run WAS with Oracle JVM so it is clearly something wrong in your description of the environment. Your `war` might be built incorrectly.

Comment: W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource org/osgi/service/application/ApplicationAdminPermission.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.app-1.6.0.jar
                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:147)